# How to find the SharePoint Path from Office 365 using OAuth2 Client Credential Flow

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, office365

### Problem

I have been trying to figure out how to find a SharePoint path for a user when using OAuth2 **Client Credential Flow** (where an application has permission to read all users' SharePoint files using an Office 365 administrator's one-time acceptance)

I have my client application setup in Azure and am able to read files if I hard-code the SharePoint URL - so I know it is setup correctly.

But I need to "discover" the SharePoint URL so it will be change-tolerant and reusable across customers.

### Related Articles:

[Different OAuth2 Flows](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/looking-at-the-different-oauth2-flows-supported-in-azuread-for-office-365-apis)

[Using OAuth2 Flow for Exchange](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx)

### Code

```
var azureAdAuthority = "https://login.windows.net/{tenant-id}/oauth2/authorize".Replace("{tenant-id}", tenantId);
var discoveryUri = "https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/";
var discoveryResourceUri = "https://api.office.com/discovery/";

// discover contact endpoint
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certFilePath, certFilePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
var clientAssertion = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, cert);
var userIdentifier = new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);
var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(userObjectId);

// create auth context
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(azureAdAuthority, false);

// create O365 discovery client 
var discovery = new DiscoveryClient(new Uri(discoveryUri),
    () => authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(discoveryResourceUri, clientAssertion, userIdentifier).AccessToken);

// query discovery service for endpoint for 'calendar' endpoint
var dcr = await discovery.DiscoverCapabilityAsync("MyFiles");
```

This and many other variations throw exceptions from the AcquireTokenSilent function.

If I don't use a "userIdentifier" and call the AcquireToken function it succeeds, but the DiscoverCapabilityAsync function fails.